# Select rows where child rows do not exist in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following tables

```
Clubs
- Id
- Name

Members
- Id
- ClubId linked to Clubs.Id
- Name
```

How can I write a query in LINQ that will give me a list of Clubs that don't have any members?

PS: what should be the correct terminology here? The members table is a * of the Clubs table. (not parent and child but?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I write a query in LINQ that will give me a list of Clubs that
>   don't have any members?

You can do this:

```
from m in db.Members
where !db.Clubs.Any( c => (c.Id == m.ClubId))
select m;
```

**For your second question:**

> should be the correct terminology here? The members table is a * of
>   the Clubs table. (not parent and child but?)

No, it is not. This is not a parent and child relation, because a member can exist with out a club. The relation between `Members` and `Clubs` in your case is a, what they called in UML, ***Aggregation***. But the parent and child relation or what they called ***Composition***, i.e ***Has a*** relation, the child object can't exist with out a parent. And that is not your case.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you a list of clubs without members:

```
from c in db.Clubs
where !db.Members.Any( m => m.ClubId == c.Id)
select c;
```

But I suspect the correct way to do this would be a many to many relationship with an intermediate table. (Your data could be an exception?) If you belong to 3 Clubs would you have your record in the Members table 3 times? You have to if the ClubId is in the Members table.  A change of address would have to be done to 3 records. This is not the correct way.

So removing ClubId from the Members table and adding a table Members_Clubs with just MemberId and ClubId would allow you to associate a single member with many clubs.

Then the statement would look like:

```
from c in db.Clubs
where !db.Members_Clubs.Any( mc => mc.ClubId == c.Id)
select c;
```

In this, neither entity is the "parent" or the "child".  This makes them associative entities.

Comment: If this is against SQL tables, SelectMany translates to a left join, and might be a better option.  A .Where on a subtable might result in all records being fetched and then filtered client side.